# Solver VBA macro across multiple columns and rows

Tags: vba, excel, solver

New to VBA.  Scoured the internet, can't come up with solution (but I learned a lot in the process).

I am running solver to solve for a revenue number that will give me a specified profit margin given certain expenses.  I've got that all set and a Sub that will perform this task properly for one month.  However, I am trying to apply this to 12 columns (12-months).  Then step the loop down 19 rows.  Run solver across those 12 columns and so on 6-times.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Monthly()


SolverReset
SolverAdd CellRef:="$d$40", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$d$41"
SolverOk SetCell:="$d$40", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$d$24", Engine _
    :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve True

SolverReset
SolverAdd CellRef:="$e$40", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$e$41"
SolverOk SetCell:="$e$40", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$e$24", Engine _
    :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve True
```

This is an example that would get me January and February.  Want it to run through the remaining 10-months (without having to copy and paste this 10-times and manually type in the cell coordinates for F-O columns).  Then the code below is for the step down 19 rows:

```
SolverReset
SolverAdd CellRef:="$d$59", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$d$60"
SolverOk SetCell:="$d$59", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$d$43", Engine _
    :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve True


End Sub
```

And again, I would like this to run across 12 columns and step down 19 rows to do it again 4 more times.  So the end result is solver running 6 times across 12 columns for a total of 72 times.  I would prefer to not type those cell coordinates that many times, and it's probably taxing on my CPU to do it that way. Thanks!

UPDATE:

I am now getting an error, seemingly for no reason.  This thing was working great.

```
Sub MonthlySolve1a()
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("D40")
    MonthlySolve1b c
End Sub

'solve 12 months
Sub MonthlySolve1b(c As Range)
Dim m  As Long
For m = 1 To 12

    SolverReset
    SolverAdd CellRef:=c.Address(), Relation:=2, FormulaText:=c.Offset(1, 0).Address()
    SolverOk SetCell:=c.Address(), MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, _
            ByChange:=c.Offset(-16, 0).Address(), Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve True

    Set c = c.Offset(0, 1)
Next m
End Sub
```

I probably did something stupid in my sheet that messed it up, but any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Somehow the Tools>References> Solver checkbox got unchecked.  Problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop to run solver on each month:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("D40")
    Monthly c
End Sub


'solve 12 months
Sub Monthly(c As Range)
    Dim m  As Long
    For m = 1 To 12

        SolverReset
        SolverAdd CellRef:=c.Address(), Relation:=2, FormulaText:=c.Offset(1, 0).Address()
        SolverOk SetCell:=c.Address(), MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, _
                ByChange:=c.Offset(-16, 0).Address(), Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverSolve True

        Set c = c.Offset(0, 1)
    Next m
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent- worked great.  I can use this script 6 times and simply change the D40 address to D59, D78, etc. (stepping down 19 each time).  Thanks a lot!