# Excel Solver Macro works for only one row

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to automize the solver function in excel. The idea was to select a cell and have the objective cell filled out as the currently selected cell, have the value it is supposed to get to filled out as a value of one nearby cell and the changing variable cell as the cell right bellow that.[Here is an example of how the solver was supposed to be set up (the value to is the cell G17)

[image]

So I attempted to use the Macro bellow, however it works only for one row! For the first one it solves everything as intended, but for any other rows bellow that nothing happens, when it is run. No error, just nothing.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    ChangingCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -13)
    TargetCell = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -13).Value
    SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=TargetCell, ByChange:=ChangingCell, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=TargetCell, ByChange:=ChangingCell, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
End Sub
```

What could be the problem? Thanks for help.

Comment: Your screenshot has both Target and the Variable cell on the same row, but your code has them on different rows?

Comment: Using Solver in a loop - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35610519/478884

Answer (score 0):

- Adding `For` loop to iterate each row and apply solver

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SolverForAll()
    Dim ChangingCell As Range
    Dim TargetCell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Const START_ROW = 17
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow > START_ROW Then
        For i = START_ROW To lastRow
            ChangingCell = Cells(i, "G").Value
            TargetCell = Cells(i - 1, "G").Value
            SolverOk SetCell:=Cells(i, "T"), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=TargetCell, ByChange:=ChangingCell, _
                Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
            SolverSolve
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

---

- Sovler does NOT change the location of `ActiveCell`. The code only applies Solver for the first row.
- If you prefer to apply Solver only for a row each time, you just need to add a line to move `ActiveCell`

```vb
Sub Macro3()
    ChangingCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -13)
    TargetCell = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -13).Value
    SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=TargetCell, ByChange:=ChangingCell, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=TargetCell, ByChange:=ChangingCell, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first code doesn't really seem to do anything, I am not sure why. The second approach would be ideal for me, but for some reason, the ActiveCell just does not change even with this line of code. I played with it for a while, but it still only uses that one cell as the ActiveCell.

Comment: You can just test the last line. It should work well.